# Evaluating multiclass imbalanced problem per class

Tags: classification, unbalanced-classes, supervised-learning, semi-supervised-learning

For a multiclass imbalanced problem, `accuracy` is not a good metric to evaluate model performance. Equally, `accuracy` is a global metric, so nothing like `accuracy` per-class (doesn't make sense).

`Scikit-learn` provides the `classification_report`  function so one can evaluate model's `precision/recall` per class, e.g:

```
classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names)
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

     Class:0      0.703     0.896     0.788      4491
     Class:1      0.048     0.147     0.072        75
     Class:2      0.368     0.503     0.425      1097
     Class:3      0.937     0.850     0.892     17162
     Class:4      0.529     0.177     0.265       311

    accuracy                          0.832     23136
   macro avg      0.517     0.515     0.488     23136
weighted avg      0.856     0.832     0.838     23136
```

Are there other metrics that evaluate per-class so I can evaluate my model across more metrics than `precision/recall/f1`? The goal is to assess the model on a per-class basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Precision and recall are misleading just like accuracy is. Every criticism against accuracy at [Why is accuracy not the best measure for assessing classification models?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312780/1352)
 applies equally to precision and recall.

Use probabilistic predictions for class membership, and evaluate these using proper [scoring-rules](/questions/tagged/scoring-rules), e.g., the Brier score or the log score. More information and pointers to literature can be found at [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).

If you really want to, you can calculate the average of such scores over instances that fall into particular classes, but the properness of these scores refers to their *overall* performance, and I suspect that looking at scores per class may be misleading.

You may be interested in [this earlier answer of mine](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/312787/1352).